# From observation, it was defined that the probability, that it will snow on the first of January, is equal to 0.4.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

From observation, it was defined that the probability that it will snow on the first of January is equal to 0.4. Let $X$ be the number of days without snow on the first January during the $5$ years.

Find $Pr(X<2)$. What it means?

**My Working:**

Now answering to the given question of calculating $P(X<2)$ is pretty easy once we know the pdf or cdf of random variable $X$ which can be found easily, once we know the distribution of random variable $X$. As far as I have understood $X$~$BIN(5,0.6)$ where $p=1-0.4=0.6$ is probability of success that it won't snow on the first of January, and $n=5$ is number of trials. Am I going in right direction? If not please guide me.

Comment: The direction looks good, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The probability of seeing no snow is $0.6$, and we get 5 repetitions of that event, so you need to calculate the probability that $Bin(0.6, 5) < 2$ (probability of getting fewer than 2 snowy days)

If you prefer to work with the days of snow rather than the days without it, you could also calculate the probability that $Bin(0.4, 5) > 3$ (probability that it snow in more than 3 attempts)

Comment: That is also a good approach. Thanks man!